# how to retrieve data from array of form fields

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, associative-array

I want to retrieve data from array of form fields , how do I do it

View:

```
 <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="options[ac]" id="ac"> <label for="ac">Air Conditioning</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="options[parking]" id="car"> <label for="car">Car Parking</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="options[cards]" id="card"> <label for="card">Credit & Debit Card</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="options[tv]" id="tv"> <label for="tv">TV</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="options[wifi]" id="wifi"> <label for="wifi">Wi-Fi</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="options[beverages]" id="beverage"> <label for="beverage">Beverages</labell>


<input name="option[adress]" class="form-control" type="text" 
placeholder="Address" required>

 <input name="option[email]" class="form-control" type="text"     placeholder="email" required>
```

I want to display name and value of each as:
eg.adress:abcd
   wifi :yes email:abcd

how do i assign the associative array option i have tried

```
    $arr=$this->input->post('option[]');

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo($key);
    }
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor, simply place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data that gets printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Comment: paste your full form, so that we know that you are actually using a post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->input-post('field_name') looks in the $_POST array for a key named 'field_name'. Try this.

```
$arr=$this->input->post('option[adress]');

foreach($arr as $key => $value) 
{
    echo($key);
}
```

Comment: You would be wise to always check the return from `input_post('field_name')` as it will return NULL if 'field_name' is not in the $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$arr=$this->input->post('option');
```

Comment: no error coming: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$arr = $_POST["option"];

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
   echo $key.":".$value;
}
?>
```